# Overlap Report Elements on top of an Image Control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting

I had a problem with designing my report on Visual Studio using C# Windows Forms. I have already designed my report and I placed some elements (Textboxes) on top of an Image Controls (2 logos). But when I run my program, The textboxes are displaying below or above the image. I just want those textboxes to overlap on the picture I placed as background.

Is there any way to lock those other elements on top of an image control?
or place other controls on top of image controls?

Please Help.

Im using

- Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Version 11.0.50727
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7
- Windows 10 Operating System

Thanks.

Comment: This is a question that would probably benefit from images. Please [edit] your question and include images of the desired result and the current form.

Comment: I don't know if I completely understand your question, but what about using a `Panel`, set its `BackgroundImage` and place the controls inside it? Coordinates of the textboxes would then always be relative to your image.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the item, select Layout, and then Bring To Front, or Send to Back, to determine what comes in front and what in the back.